# MYSQL + Node.JS Post Request Confusion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, networking, http-post

I am very new to networking and I have this code which, when I use a REST API like Postman, does exactly what I want it to do:

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next){
var reqObj = req.body;        
    console.log(reqObj);
    req.getConnection(function(err, conn){
    if(err)
    {
        console.error('SQL Connection error: ', err);
        return next(err);
    }
    else
    {
        var query = conn.query("INSERT INTO coordinates (id,lat,lon) VALUES(3,2,1);");
        if(err)
        {
            console.error('SQL error: ', err);
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json("Coordinates sent.");
    }
})
}  );
```

That is, it sends the query request to the MYSQL database. My question is, how do I do this without using Postman to send the POST request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless you make a post request from within your application or something. If you don't intend on sending data, you can just make it a GET request by changing

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next){
```

to

```
router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
```

Then you can just go to the relevant URL from your browser. If you're using chrome and you just wanna see the JSON data, I'd also recommend installing the JSONView chrome extension.

**EDIT**

Here's the example request using [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var objectData = {
    name: 'Bruce',
    alias: 'Batman'
};
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://your.api/endpoint/',
    body: objectData,
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

request(options).then(function(response){
    // handle success response
}, function(error){
    // handle error response
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a post request within the application then - I'm just not sure how. Obviously my knowledge is very limited here :)

Comment: Is your application running on the same node server? If so, you can use the npm request library: https://github.com/request/request. If you're using any kind of framework like angular, react, or mithril, those frameworks should have built in ways to perform requests :)

Comment: I also really like the request-promise library: https://github.com/request/request-promise. If you're not familiar with promises, you can read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: It is running on the same server.

Comment: Is there a "quick translation" you could provide me with the npm request library?

Comment: There's an example in my post for you now.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Sorry for asking so much, but how would I go about submitting the MySQL query?

Comment: I actually ended up using a similar library, promise-mysql, to achieve what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got that squared away! Happy coding!